# does code signing encrypt our original software coding also?

Tags: certificate, code-signing

I just want to confirm when we sign our windows application code for a digital certificate, does the code signing encrypt our original software coding as well?

Comment: I clearly now that what code signing certificate does in the sense of shrink-wrapped package that can clearly determine who published the software and whether or not the package has been tampered with or opened.
My question is that i want to confirm that does certificate encrypt our original code?

Comment: What platform/device? Add the comment to the question, just click "edit" and delete the comment.